LTspice: how can I simulate this RLC?

I'm not sure on how I should add the voltage and the current

I’m voting to close this question because academic questions need an attempt at a solution

Add ground and name the node top node, for example plus.
Use the initial condition SPICE directive:
.ic V(plus)=5

to set the votlage.
For the inductor current, use the name of the inductor, for example L1.
.ic I(L1)=2

If the dot convention is not in your favor and you end up with -2 A, either flip the inductor or state -2 A.
Make sure your simulation setting does not include "skip initial point calculation".
